# Abstract static javascript method workaround

Tags: javascript, typescript, abstract-class

I have class `ChildA` and a class `ChildB` and a class `Base`.

`ChildA` and `ChildB` inherits from `Base`. The constructor of `Base` takes 1 parameter, called `id`.

I need to add a method, `validate` to `Base` class, so that:

1. Every class that inherits from `Base` should be forced to implement.
2. This method will be executed before I have an `id` which i can use in order to create an instance of `ChildA` / `ChildB`.

Because of #1, it feels like this method should be abstract.
Because of #2, it feels like this method should be static.
However, typescript doesn't support abstract static functions.

Eventually, the usage should be that the `validate` methods of `ChildA` and `ChildB` are invoked from some other method of `Base`, let's call it `bla`, Something like:

```
abstract class Base {
    id: string;
    protected static abstract validate(): boolean;

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    bla() {
        const r = (this.constructor as typeof Base).validate();
        // do something with r
    }
}

class ChildA extends Base {
    protected static validate(): boolean {
        // validate stuff
        return true;
    }
}

class ChildB extends Base {
    protected static validate(): boolean {
        // validate stuff
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't define `validate` as both abstract and static so I'm not sure how I can achieve what I need, maybe I can use interface for it, but not sure how exactly.

**I'm not writing the code from scratch, so I have limited freedom to change things.**

Comment: Where are you going to call `validate` as a static method? It is that place where you'll need to require the concrete class to implement the method, regardless whether it is declared on `Base` or not. Admittedly, you'll get the type error in the "wrong" place, i.e. where you are calling the method on an incompatible receiver, not where you are defining the concrete class to inherit from `Base`, but at least it's still typesafe.

Comment: I did it @jcalz

Comment: I think this is discussed in depth at [ms/TS#34516](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34516) and while there are various workarounds, none enforce that subclasses implement the static method the way you want.  And it's not obvious what should be allowed in general, so this is a tricky thing to do properly.  Personally I might just give up and write a runtime-only check like [this](//tsplay.dev/NVOzvm), which at least lets you *use* the static method.  Let me know if this fully addresses the question and I should write up an answer, or if I'm missing something (and if so, what)

Comment: Thank you, I understand the solution you're suggesting, but I don't think the runtime check is good enough (at this point at least). Can't I somehow use interface instead of the abstract part?

Comment: What do you mean by "somehow use interface"?  You can define an interface the static side needs to implement but you can't *require* subclasses to conform to it; there's no "`extends static`" either.  Perhaps you just want a class factory function instead of `abstract` at all, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqybjm) shows.  Do you want to see that written up as an answer instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
abstract class Base {
  id: string;
  protected abstract validate(): boolean;

  constructor(id: string) {
    const r = this.bla();

    console.log(r);

    this.id = id;
  }

  bla() {
    const r = this.validate();
    // do something with r
    return r;
  }
}

class ChildA extends Base {
  protected validate(): boolean {
    // validate stuff
    return true;
  }
}

class ChildB extends Base {
  protected validate(): boolean {
    // validate stuff
    return false;
  }
}

const childa = new ChildA('1');
const childb = new ChildB('2');
```

This should hopefully fulfill the two criteria you have. I've opted to keep the methods `protected`

- Every class that inherits from Base should be forced to implement.
- This method will be executed before I have an id which i can use in order to create an instance of ChildA / ChildB.

If you need the `validate` method to be static, so you can call it before you create a child, then you could do one of two things

1. Have logic in the constructor of the Child which has validation logic. If it's in valid, it can throw an error.
2. Create a builder object which can build and validate your params before it builds a child. https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder

Comment: Thank you, but I can't do #1 cause I need the `id` in order to create an instance and there's no `id` at this point in the flow.
Regarding #2, I guess it's possible to use builder, but this change is relatively big. I might end up doing something like it but wanted to check if there's a shorter, more elegant way of approaching it.